# Why is sinf() so slow when compiling my code on Linux/ARMv7?

Tags: linux, performance, math, gcc, trigonometry

The same C code with the math `sin()` function runs much slower when I compile my program on ARMv7 compared to what I get on Windows. I'm compiling with `-O2 -Wall -Wextra -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 -march=armv7 -std=c++11` and my gcc is `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`.

I don't think it's just that sin() is not so fast for real time operations, and I know that a good compromise for faster sin functions would be using a lookup table, but what I'm experiencing here is probably an anomaly or a bug in the compiler, as it really takes too long to run the sin() function.

My program creates a few wavetables at the startup, and while it start almost instantly on Windows, it takes roughly 25-30 seconds to start on Linux/ARM...

Here's some code that shows where the `sinf()` function is used that slows down everything.

```
for (int n = 0; n < 73; ++n)
{
    // Max number of harmonics
    int hrm = int(16000.f / twf[n]);

    // Set vectors
    basic_wf.assign(wavelength[n], 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < wavelength[n]; ++i)
    {
        // Add harmonics
        for (int h = 1; h < hrm; ++h)
        {
            const float harm = 0.14f * (sinf((float)i * FACTOR * twf[n] * (float)h) / (float)h);
            if (h % 2 == 0) basic_wf[i] -= harm;    // add even negative harmonic
            else basic_wf[i] += harm;               // add odd positive harmonic
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm filling 73 tables with a sawtooth waveform adding the required number of harmonig for each frequency. The lower the pitch of the note, the higher the number of harmonics (actual sin() calculations). This runs almost instantly on Windows... takes a lifetime on my Linux box.

Comment: Isn't that whole processor just a lot slower than the other? What is the other processor you're comparing this with anyway, probably some i5 or i7 right? Obviously going to blow the average A9 straight out of the water

Comment: Is your problem compiling your code, or **running** it?

Comment: The problem is in run time, but the comparison between the two processor is not really important in my case. The program is huge, contains lots of real time audio algorithms, and if I exclude only the parts that use the sin() functions, they run almost with the same speed. I'm working on a benchmark reference: I know that if someting takes 100 mS to run on my i7 it takes ~ 900 mS to run on the A9, so before compiling anything I run my benchmark so I know how it will perform on the A9 before running it.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, some A9 SoCs don't have a NEON FPU:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A9  You wouldn't have one of those?

Comment: What is your question exactly? A philosophical discussion on the reason or ways to avoid invoking the sine function that often?

Comment: I'm on a Samsung Exynos 4412, it has a NEON FPU.

Comment: I take it your computation is single precision throughout? The mention of `sinf()` suggest it, but later on you also mention `sin()`. Do you know the approximate range of the inputs to `sinf()`? Trigonometric functions may be slow for arguments of large magnitude. What kind of ARM platform is this, does it include NEON SIMD version 2 with support for the fused-multiply-add instruction `VFMA.F32`? Have you tried compiling with `-ffast-math`?

Comment: Compiling with `-ffast-math` makes no difference. Yes, it's single precision and the Exynos 4412 has a NEON FPU.

Comment: Your working hypothesis is that the execution speed of the toolchain's `sinf()` implementation is too blame. I could post a fast alternative implementation of `sinf()` which would allow you to get a second data point. It is C99 code, and relies heavily on fused-multiply add in the form of the `fmaf()` standard math function. Unless the Exynos 4412 has native support for the FMA operation, `fmaf()` will map to really slow emulation code. I wouldn't want to post the code as an answer if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It looks like the argument to `sinf()` could get rather large? What is the maximum magnitude observed for `(float)i * FACTOR * twf[n] * (float)h`?

Comment: With `n=0` the freqency is 69.295, the highest `i` is (44100/69.295=) 636 and the highest `h` is (16000/69.295=) 230.89 so maghitude is 636 * (2*pi/44100) * 69.295 * 230.98 = 1450.35618275

Answer (score 1):

The code suggests, and your analysis in comments confirmed, that the magnitude of the argument to `sinf()` can get quite large, certainly up to several thousand. Accurate argument reduction used in common library implementations of trig functions can be computationally intensive and thus slow for large arguments, especially when the hardware platform has no support for fused-multiply add operations. This is likely a contributing factor in the low `sinf()` performance you observe.

You mentioned in a comment that the operands to `sinf()` include a factor of π. This indicates you would actually want to use `sinpif()`, where sinpi(x) = sin(x*π). The sinpi function was introduced in the IEEE-754 (2008) floating-point standard but has not made it into language standards yet. A few tool chains offer it as an extension, however. The advantage of `sinpi()` is that it requires only a very simple argument reduction regardless of the magnitude of the arguments, which can reduce excution time considerably. This results in improved performance. Since the multiplication by π is implicit, it can also offer improved accuracy over the discrete approach using `sinf()`.

I am showing an exemplary C99 implementation of `sinpif()` below. Note that this code relies heavily on the standard math function `fmaf()` to achieve high processing speed and excellent accuracy. If your CPU does not have hardware support for the fused multiply-add (FMA) operation, this function will execute very slowly, since correct emulation of `fmaf()` is non-trivial. Since the code is written in modular fashion, you would want to configure the compiler to apply the maximum amount of function inlining, or add appropriate inlining attributes to all constituent functions.

As you indicate that your hardware platform does not offer native support for FMA, you can replace each `fmaf(a,b,c)` with `(a*b+c)`, at some loss in accuracy. According to my tests, the maximum ulp error increases to 1.71364 ulps. This is still very good, but `my_sinf()` is no longer faithfully rounded anymore in that case, which is generally considered a desirable property.

```c
/* Argument reduction for sinpi, cospi, sincospi. Reduces to [-0.25, +0.25] */
float trig_red_pi_f (float a, int *i)
{
    float r;
    r = rintf (a + a);
    *i = (int)r;
    r = a - 0.5f * r;
    return r;
}

/* Approximate cos(pi*x) for x in [-0.25,0.25]. Maximum ulp error = 0.87440 */
float cospif_poly (float s)
{
    float r;
    r =              0x1.d98dcep-3f;   //  2.31227502e-1f
    r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.55c4e8p+0f);  // -1.33503580e+0f
    r = fmaf (r, s,  0x1.03c1d4p+2f);  //  4.05870533e+0f
    r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.3bd3ccp+2f);  // -4.93480206e+0f
    r = fmaf (r, s,  0x1.000000p+0f);  //  1.00000000e+0f
    return r;
}

/* Approximate sin(pi*x) for x in [-0.25,0.25]. Maximum ulp error = 0.96441 */
float sinpif_poly (float a, float s)
{
    float r;
    r =             -0x1.2dc6f8p-1f;   // -5.89408636e-1f
    r = fmaf (r, s,  0x1.46602ep+1f);  //  2.54981017e+0f
    r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.4abbc0p+2f);  // -5.16770935e+0f
    r = r * s;
    r = fmaf (r, a, -0x1.777a5cp-24f * a); // PI_lo // -8.74227766e-8f
    r = fmaf (a, 0x1.921fb6p+1f, r);       // PI_hi //  3.14159274e+0f
    return r;
}

/* Compute sin(pi*x) and cos(pi*x) based on quadrant */
float sinpif_cospif_core (float a, int i)
{
    float r, s;
    s = a * a;
    r = (i & 1) ? cospif_poly (s) : sinpif_poly (a, s);
    if (i & 2) {
        r = 0.0f - r; // don't change "sign" of NaNs or create negative zeros
    }
    return r;
}

/* maximum ulp error = 0.96411 */
float my_sinpif (float a)
{
    float r;
    int i;
    r = trig_red_pi_f (a, &i);
    r = sinpif_cospif_core (r, i);
    /* IEEE-754: sinPi(+n) is +0 and sinPi(-n) is -0 for positive integers n */
    r = (a == truncf (a)) ? (a * 0.0f) : r;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Apparently my Exynos 4412 has a NEON V1 that does not support VFMA.F32.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what already Napier and Co. did to compute logarithm tables -- or more precisely tables for the powers of `1.000001` or similar.

If you need a vector of values `sin(k*w)` then compute `c1000=cos(1000*w)` and `s1000=sin(1000*w)`, set

```
c[0] = 1; s[0] = 0;
c[1000]=c1000; s[1000] = s1000;
```

and then iteratively

```
c[1000*(k+1)] = c1000*c[1000*k]-s1000*s[1000*k];
s[1000*(k+1)] = c1000*s[1000*k]+s1000*c[1000*k];
```

and then fill the gaps using `c1=cos(w)` and `s1=sin(w)` again using the trigonometric identities, 1000 steps forward or if you want 500 forward and 500 backward. This multi-level approach should keep the accumulation of floating point errors small enough.

On "big" processors there should be no large difference, the cost of 2 multiplications and a sincos evaluation should be comparable. In your case there should be some advantage in the multiplicative procedure.